# Sitecore 9.3 sorting issues

Tags: sitecore-client

I'm new to Sitecore and I've been tasked with sorting items on a few templates, using the standard `Sortorder` field.

The issue is that a few fields are behaving erratically and disregarding the Sortorder values, but only for a few items while positioning correctly on others.

In the below example, a "Navigation" appears in two different positions disregarding the Sortorder value, it should be placed as in the first case.

[image]

[image]

Similar issue is also happening with other templates on other items.

Comment: Can you please share the sort order value you are using for the different fields?

Comment: hero has 100, product overview 200, and so on.
navigation has 600

Comment: And can you please share which field is in which template?

Comment: Does 2nd case extend **Navigation** section with additional fields by any chance? If so it might be the root cause.

Comment: both navigations use the same template with no additions.
I have this same sorting issue with other unrelated fields in other unrelated items, the ones in the question were just the best example

Answer (score 1):

The **Sortorder** takes over the default sorting by **Name**. When changing the **Sortorder** manually Sitecore will insert a value into the **Sortorder** (`_sortorder`) standard field in the *Appearance* section.

The higher Sortorder's value the lower item's position will be. Also if an item has an `empty` or invalid Sortorder value then Sitecore will use `100` for calculations by default.

So, please carefully check the **Sortorder** values for all items especially from the second case. And then check a **Subitems sorting** standard field (it is in the same *Appearance* section just below the Sortorder one) for the *parent item* of your items as the **Subitems Sorting** can simply override your expected sorting logic.